# Building chart where single peace is composed from several spreadsheet columns

Tags: charts, google-sheets, spreadsheet

We've got following subset of data structure in google spreadsheet

[image]

You can ignore `~Sentiment` column. Current issue is in figuring out how to compose following charts.

We have 2 charts one for `SUCCESS` column and other for `FAILURE` column, both of these can have 4 peaces and these peaces are

`UP UP` `DOWN DOWN` `UP DOWN` `DOWN UP` you can probably already see correlation with `Previous direction` and `Sentiment direction`.

We need these charts to compare success rate of each `UP / DOWN` combination, i.e. first row would add success to `UP UP` combination for SUCCESS chart, second row would add success to `DOWN DOWN` combination in FAILURE chart and so on. 1 and -1 represent success and failure respectively.

Here is how I envision 2 charts looking (data is placeholder)

[image]

---

[image]

Comment: @pnuts for SUCCESS (green one) accumulation of `1` and `-1` from column C, For example first 3 rows will result in `UP UP` value of 2

Comment: @pnuts thats just a placeholder value and this subset of data is small fraction from the spreadsheet. My bad for not mentioning, will edit the question

Comment: @pnuts could do, need to update it after work, output example is just a quick drawing made in photoshop to provide somewhat more context, but I guess it should reflect it via data as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the key to the solution is through **SUMPRODUCT**

You can get the spread of *UP UP success* for example using:

`=SUMPRODUCT(($F$2:$F$21="UP")*($G$2:$G$21="UP")*$C$2:$C$21)`

This assumes the last row index is 21. To get *UP DOWN success* just change the second "UP" in the formula to "DOWN".

To get the spread of *UP UP failure* just apply the formula to the failure column like so:

`=SUMPRODUCT(($F$2:$F$21="UP")*($G$2:$G$21="UP")*$D$2:$D$21)`

---

My spreadsheet looked like so:

[image: Spreadsheet example]

And the resultant success graph without any refinement looks like:

[image: Spreadsheet graph]